Why is the shadow of the 3D viewport inconsistent with the effect rendered after shadow capture?
I have a question about shadow capture. The PNG output after shadow capture is directly superimposed on the background. Why is the shadow much darker than the viewport appears?


pls show your compositing node tree

I overlaid the PNG on a separate background image in Adobe XD

In fact, I want to get a png sequence with a shadow as light as the one seen in the viewport, and then make it into an apng and deliver it to the website developer for mouse interaction animation, so I cannot use the compositor in blender to synthesize the background.
